# QT, advance GUI, fancy context menu

Tags: c++, qt

i am working on a Qt project and i want to make a fancy context pie right click.... menu.

like the one in the image

[image]bellow

I am using QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, and setting the background transparent by

```
 setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
 setStyleSheet("background: transparent ;border: none;");
```

what i want to achieve is when user hove over the circle and it is a sub-menu then a pie menu will appears but,

The problem is:

sadly mouse events will not emit unless its touching a solid pixel from my QGraphicsView, so when mouse cursor hove over a sub-menu the red pie will appear BUT as soon as i move to click on a sector from the pie it will disappear because i am no longer hovering over the orange circle.

any another good idea or solution so i can get mouse events over my transparent area (i will calculate the distance from the orange circle and if the mouse IN RANGE the pie will stay shown)

thanks.

Comment: is your context menu is using QMenu and you put graphic view on QMenu? Or the context menu is in graphics view?

Comment: no i am not using the QMenu at all , just QGraphicsView and QWidget and a class inherited from QGraphicsItem that represent a clickable item(circle in the image) .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this :

- Hover the orange one and the sub menu appear.
- Keep the sub menu appear until your mouse hover nothing or hover another circle menu. When you move your mouse to sub menu -> it means you hover thing, so the sub menu will still there. If your sub menus are all same, so when you hover another circle, just move sub menu position and maybe set some property.
- Make sure that your orange circle and the sub menu is overlap, so moving mouse from orange to sub menu will not trigger "hover nothing"